# Angular Material 2: md-select doesn't show initial value

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-material2, md-select

Good evening,
I'm using Angular Material 2.0.0 beta1, and I've got troubles with md-select. Here is the code:

```
<md-select placeholder="Stato" [(ngModel)]="detail.doc_dst_serial"  name="stato"  >
     <md-option *ngFor="let status of statuses" [value]="status.dst_serial" >
        {{status?.description}}
     </md-option>
</md-select>
```

It correctly saves data in the ngModel and, consequently, in the database, but when I close and re-open the page, the selection is gone, with unset initial value.

Comment: I assume you're retrieving the stored value from a service in `ngOnInit` and assigning it to the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably thanks to the update of the beta it works.. I haven't changed anything